# A better where-is command?

Tags: key-bindings, help

I'm trying to setup a way to find keys I want to use but keep forgetting.

(I know there is where-is (C-w) and describe-binds, describe-mode. )

I want the following,

- initiate a command to search for keys (let's M-o)
- in a minibuffer (or helm buffer), type "help go back"
- it shows the corresponding hot keys

It is different from `where-is` in two ways

1. it shows the key sequence right there without "entering" another buffer
2. I can search with my own "keyword"
   for instance help command might be named help-go-back but I might be more comfortable to use "help before"
   (there are command names which are hard to remember)

I'm thinking to use a file to provide those values, for instance

```
* help
- go before:  C-c C-b , g b : back, previous 
- go previous page: p 


* org 
- demote 
  - single item: M-right    
  - subtree: M-S-right : children
```

I can think of writing a custom helm source (?) for this, but wondering if there's a better way

Alternative (close but not perfect) way of reusing existing capability is

- make `where-is` to show the keys in the list (not after selecting the command)
- make `describe-mode` to show more key bindings (not just emacs key bindings but evil-state related key bindings)
- Append `help` or `org` or any sub headings to the leaf node, so that I can just `isearch` on the file (but prefarably automate the appending step)

Comment: FWIW, what you're requesting isn't clear to me. Hopefully it will be clear to someone who can help.

Comment: What I understand is that when you initiate a keybinding, like `M-o`, you would like to be able to quickly get help about what command can be invoked, with the corresponding key suffixes. I think it is worth trying [`which-key`](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key). [`embark`](https://github.com/oantolin/embark#working-with-sets-of-possible-targets) also provides this kind of feature but is more difficult to set up and to use.

Comment: You are mentioning 'helm source'; does it mean you are using [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). Because, if I understand you correctly, `helm-M-x` provides what you ask for by default (except that you can not use a 'custom search term'). However, like `where-is`, it shows the keybindings for the 'current buffer', so if you would like to look up keybindings for `help-mode` then you should invoke `helm-M-x` from a `help-mode` buffer (and type e.g. "help back")

Comment: @Drew i'm working on implementing it, i'll let you know what i come up with,

Comment: @TristanRiehs yeah embark seems to provide something similar, but I gave up on it because it'd require me to abondon helm or something dramatic

Comment: @dalanicolai yes, I think you are mentioning C-h m (describe mode) or C-h b (describe-bindings which is overloaded by helm-descbinds for me) it's close, but I think helm-descbinds fall short when I have evil mode, it doesn't show correct bindings for current state, and two there are just too many keys so I have hard time to find what I learned and forgot. (it's a good tool when i look up something new)

Comment: @eugene Why learning embark would force you to abandon any other package ? I do not understand.

Comment: @eugen I mean `helm-M-x` (not C-h m or C-h b). Try doing `M-x` `helm-M-x` from some help buffer, and search for `help back`.

Comment: @TristanRiehs spacemacs seemed to support helm / ivy / compleseus ? and seems to suggest 'exclusiveness' of 'completion' framework , and i though embark was not compatible with helm, I might be mistaken ..

Comment: @dalanicolai oh I always though helm-M-x was refering to M-x, Thanks, I found something new. it shows keys for some command I ran, and doesn't show keys for some though

Comment: @eugene Embark itself is not a completion framework. It is often used with [Vertico](https://github.com/minad/vertico) which is one. I think Embark will not break Spacemacs.

Comment: @TristanRiehs thank you for pointing it out. I'll check it out

Comment: @TristanRiehs I made switch to embark + Vertico, it offers what I always found missing (the capability to switch and chain commands , which embark-action and embark-become offers) thank you for suggestion.